# indent a paragraph of a new section

Tags: indentation

The following code is to start a new section with a paragraph indented. However the paragraph is not indented. I also need to use flush left in order to keep the alignment proper. I would appreciate it if someone can help me with this

```
\chapter{Related Work}
\label{chapter3}

\section{Channel Characterization}

\setlength{\parindent}{5ex}
\begin{flushleft}

Accurately characterizing the wireless small-scale
```

Comment: `flushleft` sets `\parindent` to `\z@` (0pt). So to have indentation you need to move `\setlength{\parindent}{5ex}` behind `\begin{flushleft}`.

Comment: Please always show a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228) instead of a code snippet. Good answers often depend on several circumstances, i.e., the class you are using. Questions without MWE are often somehow unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To indent the first paragraph of each section use:

```
\usepackage{indentfirst}
```

For the whole document to have left justification use:

```
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
```

In case you don't want indentation in your first paragraph (e.g. an abstract) use `\noindent` before your paragraph.

Comment: Thanks. How about if i want to indent paragraphs within a section and paragraphs in subsections

Comment: It should be okay, `indentfirst` indents all the first paragraphs in all sections and subsections.

Answer (score 0):

The [titlesec package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) allows to customize `\section` command and friends.
Using the non-starred version of `\titlespacing` does not prevent the indentation of the first paragraph.
This does not seem to work with flushleft, though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
% default values copied from titlesec documentation page 23
% "The starred version kills the indentation of the paragraph following the title" titlesec documentation page 4
\titlespacing{\section}
    {0pt}% left margin 
    {3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}% space above the heading
    {2.3ex plus .2ex}% space below the heading

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\section{Section~A}
\Blindtext
\section{Section~B}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This answer does not pay attention to the problem caused by usage of `flushleft`.